How to deal with flooring height difference
I decided to remove the carpet in the bedrooms of a house. Below the carpet is the bare concrete floor. However, the rest of the house has a laminate floor that sits on top of a previous tile.
I'd like to replace the previously carpeted bedrooms with a laminate floor. What options do I have for dealing with the height difference? 


How much is the height difference?  How much of that is the laminate?  How much the tile?  This is likely to be a small number, perhaps half an inch to an inch for the tile under the laminate.  Are you going with the same laminate?  If not how thick is the existing laminate.  How different will the new laminate be.

The height difference is approximately the thickness of the tile that sits under the laminate. I plan to go with a new laminate of approximately the same thickness and ideally the same exact match as the old one.

Yes, but that doesn't answer my question.  If you prefer, you can answer "How thick is the tile, including any adhesive layer?"  However, it may be easier to just measure.

Getting the exact or close enough design match might be the hardest.  The height difference is easy.  Sub flooring sheets come in different thicknesses, so one thickness or a mix of different thicknesses will match the height minus the thickness of the top tiles.

the tile layer is about 11.5mm, and the existing laminate floor sits at a height of about 18.5mm. So there's a difference of about 6mm, or just under 1/4"

Do not use plywood. Use a dense cement based product like a tile backer. This is approved for use with laminate, vinyl or wood flooring. Attach it to the concrete with mastic or thinset. There may be slight variations in the cement floor surface, so have some weights available to place on the boards to hold them down.
Another choice is 1/4" cork or one of the other LVP underlayments. Just be sure to choose something that is stiff enough to be used with the LVP you are planning to put down.
You will need a simple "T" transition between floors unless you can match the new and old flooring to your satisfaction.

Do I still need a cement-based product if my height difference is only 1/4" ?

cement base is far better than wood over cement.   You could get 1/4 inch cork but that is more expensive.  However it will lay down better and could be a better choice.  There are other underlayments as well, but be sure they are stiff enough to be approved under LVP.  They are more expensive per sq/ft also.  It may be a good decision to spend a bit more and get one of the proper underlayments. I edit my answer to reflect this.

sorry, I'm very new and I'm still not sure I understand. I think you are recommending an underlayment. Reading a bit more on the topic, I find some opinions that lean towards not needing one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0g1GSjhbNQ They say most LVP already comes with a built-in soundproofing/moisture barrier on the bottom. My existing tile does seem to have a rubber on the bottom, and I don't see a separate underlayment between the tile and the LVP. I'm curious to know if you still think I need one, and why.

@user84207, The underlayment is to help with the height difference.  Sure, you may not "need"  it for the purposes of cushioning, or as a vapor barrier, however it can be used to help when a floor height needs to be matched.  Obviously you would look for somethin that is close to the 6mm that you need to make up.

But the answer says: "With a height difference of about 1/4 inch you will need a simple "T" transition between floors." This makes it seem that a 1/4" difference can easily be addressed by a T transition, so I'm not sure if I just need the T transition, or underlayment, or both.

You need both.  Unless you can match the edges of new and old flooring to your satisfaction.  It like "you need a new tire", It goes without saying that you also will need to put air in the tire.   I made an edit to the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

You either have to use a reducer transition strip (depending on height difference of FF) or you make up the height difference by adding some subfloor (plywood or OSB) before putting in the laminate.  Or a combination of the two.
Well, I suppose another option would be to remove the existing laminate and tile, and put new laminate in all the rooms...at least that way it'd all match.

Will the plywood rot or grow mold over time?

Only if you let it get damp and stay that way.

I'm in Florida, it's very humid here. I'm afraid that without a vapor barrier that is installed perfectly, moisture and vapors will seep up from the wet and moist soil underneath, keeping the plywood humidity high and creating a breeding ground for mold.

What's below your existing floor?

The planks claim to be waterproof and have a thick rubber on the underside. Below that seems to be the concrete slab. My understanding is that the slab is somewhat porous and can allow moisture and vapors to pass through. I have a moisture meter that always detects high levels of humidity almost everywhere on the floor.

Are those tack strips in your pic nailed directly to your slab?  Hard to tell from the pic.

It does appear so, added another picture to the post. Much of Florida used to be swamp and there's a lot of moisture whether all the time. Also there's no crawl space here so my floor is directly on top of the slab.

Oh, in that case it probably behooves you to use a moisture barrier.

s/moisture whether/moisture eveywhere/

Homes in Fla are built with a moisture barrier under the concrete slab.  It is a code requirement and must be inspected and signed off before a slab can be poured.  If moisture get into a slab it is most likely a plumbing issue and not ground water.

What about settling? Can that create cracks that allow moisture to penetrate? My moisture meter always reports relatively high levels almost anywhere on the ground, across multiple homes.

If there's a moisture barrier under the slab, it won't matter if it cracks.  If it cracks and there's significant differential settlement across the crack—enough to damage the moisture barrier—you have bigger problems than just a damp floor.
